# UIView efficiency

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

I have a UIView which is essentially doing two things. The first mode lets the user control things that they've inputted. The second mode lets them input new values to interact with.

To switch between modes it animates the alpha of most of the components of the view to 0.0 and the new ones to 1.0 and it looks really nice. So far the only downside is that my nib in IB is kind of messy for editing.

I was just wondering if this was the best practice for doing this type of thing or if I should be loading a new view. The components are all just UIKit objects like buttons, sliders, labels, etc.

Comment: You can also create these objects programmatically, without using the IB. This may not be so messy.

Comment: I would suggest using a second container view with a crossfade transition.

Comment: Most of the time I stay away from nibs now. If its something that is a very static page I will use a nib but when you get animations of elements and so forth it gets too messy to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend add a second View to your xib which holds the editing elements. Then create an IBOutlet for the second view so you can access it in your view controller. When you are ready to switch between, the code that does the alpha animation can also quickly add that editing view as a subview of your main view starting with a 0.0 alpha. Then your alpha animation will bring it into view. It will look the same to you, but it'll be easier to edit in IB. I set up a simple example and took a screenshot to show you what I mean.
[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder]